# "My Calendar" Create via flow or apex?

Tags: visual-workflow, developer, calendar

I contacted salesforce support but they just told me that it's possible.

I would like to ask if there is a way to create "My Calendars" via flow or process builder. Because these are the created by every user and it's for them only. I don't want to make every user create 10/15 calendars so i would like to do it another way like flow. Using my calendar we are able to select a colour for each calendar which help our users a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not so sure about Flows. It may be necessary to use an invokable Apex action in conjunction with a Flow. However this is possible with Apex. Look into the [`CalendarView` metadata type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_calendarview.htm). The example code is taken from the example provided by Salesforce on that page. What it does is creates a new CalendarView and assigns it to users within the "Sales Group". This can be modified to meet your needs.

```java
Group userGroup = [
    SELECT Id 
    FROM Group 
    WHERE Name = 'Sales Group' 
    LIMIT 1
];
List<Id> groupId = new List<Id>{userGroup.id};

List<GroupMember> groupMembers = [
   SELECT UserOrGroupId 
   FROM GroupMember
   WHERE GroupId IN: groupId
];

List<CalendarView> calendarViews = new List<CalendarView>();
for (GroupMember groupMember : groupMembers) {
    CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(
        name = 'Opportunity Close Dates', 
        SobjectType = 'Opportunity', 
        StartField = 'CloseDate', 
        DisplayField = 'Name', 
        OwnerId = groupMember.UserOrGroupId
    );
    calendarViews.add(calendarView);
}

insert calendarViews;
```

Comment: Thanks mate i will definetely check your links.